# Flow Accumulation in R

Tags: r, software-recommendations, hydrology

Is there an ArcGIS-like implementation of Flow Accumulation for R?

What I am trying to avoid:
Using ArcGIS; Using Grass; Using RpyGEO (but will if need be)

I am aware of the landscape/hydrology packages of RSAGA, enaR, and vegan, but none of these seem to have a flow accumulation function.  I have seen previous reference to `rsaga.flow.accumulation`, but that does not appear to be support any longer.

I have tried `??flow`, but only the `RPyGEO` and a `flow path` from the Raster package show any promise.

Comment: so do you want to simply avoid the packages you mention or do you need it in R?

Comment: I would prefer it to be in R, but it is not a deal breaker.  I have ArcGIS, Spatial Analyst, and could script it in python, but I like to avoid ArcGIS b/c of license issues.  I would like to be able to run this routine on computers without Spatial Analyst licenses.  RpyGEO, as you know, still needs the SA license to run sa.FlowAccumulation.  The other packages i mentioned, RSAGA, enaR, and vegan do not have a flow accumulation function that I could find, but I would be happy to use them.

Comment: For grass you dont need a licence, its free. If you wish to use R, then you could use the spgrass6 package and then call r.terraflow from grass.

Furthermore keep in mind, that flow accumulation is a very expensive raster calculation and R is definitely not the right tool for that. Thats probably also the reason, why there is no R package doing that.

Comment: Thank you @mace.  Your point about the expense of the flow accumulation algorithm is very well taken.  Your hunch may be dead on.  The spgrass6 package may be a decent alternative.

Comment: How much of the full workflow are you looking for?  Do you want to use `R` to go from a raw DEM to the flow accumulation?  The tricky part is creating the flow direction grid; after that, a (very simple) graph algorithm does the trick.  (And, for performance reasons, you wouldn't want to code that in `R` if you could help it.)  See the recent discussion at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84309/what-algorithm-is-used-by-arcgis-watershed-tool, which includes a link to an on-line version of the original Jenson and Domingue paper (1988).

Comment: @whuber, thank you for your thoughts and the link.  My ideal would be to use R for the full work flow.  Generally [DEM -> flow direction -> accumulation -> >= threshold = stream].  The RSAGA package function `rsaga.fill.sinks` computes a flow direction using either Planchon and Darboux (2001) or Wang and Liu (2006) [it is only one of those, but the doc says "only for "wang.liu.2001"].  The consensus seems to be that `R` is a poor choice for this.  I see the reason of that argument and they outweigh my desire to contain it within `R`; I will use python for those bits. Thanks for the help/info!

Comment: One thing that makes `R` attractive is that you could encapsulate the part of the algorithm that is not good for `R` and code it in C or Fortran, which are relatively easy to interface with `R`.  This views `R` as a kind of rapid prototyping platform which can fairly easily be turned into a production environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should also take a look at TauDEM (http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/index.html)

It's a set of command-line .exe files (you run them in the Windows Command Prompt) for calculating flow direction, flow accumulation, and stream thresholds. The input and output of each command is a GeoTiff raster file. TauDEM can be installed stand-alone without ArcGIS.

In R, you can quite easily call third-party command-line executables from your R script with the system() function. There is an example how to use TauDEM in R on their website:
http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/TauDEMRScript.txt

Comment: Thank you @jirikadlec2.  This looks really promising!  This fits with the previous suggestions of using R to call more appropriate tools for the job and gives access to ArcGIS.  Also, as discussed here: [Lidar DEM](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9237/methodology-for-creating-accurate-drainage-networks-and-catchments-from-high-r?rq=1) the D-infinity flow direction algorithm fixed some of the problems with D8.  I hope to get this working shortly.

Comment: @jirikdlec2 this was just what I needed.  It is very powerful, very fast, and can be called directly from R.  The results of Dr. Tarboton's model are quite impressive.

Comment: Whitebox tools r package now offers several flow accumulation and related hydrological functions. Relatively quick to set up and super fast to run (Quick word of advice- no spaces in file paths)

Answer (score 0):

Give this article a try, it has some good leads for what you are trying to do.

[Link to flow accumulation example - R](http://figshare.com/articles/Weighted_Flow_Accumulation_R_Script/784963)

Comment: Thank you for your help @dklassen.  This is a good start, but unfortunately the author uses RpyGEO in this script.  They use `rpygeo.geoprocessor("FlowAccumulation_sa"...` which still requires an ArcGIS license.  However, if I do go the RpyGEO route, I will cite that script/poster.